# Change order of flex items when flex box width changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I have a flex box which has flex items in it, each having a certain order.

I want to set it so that when the flex box (not the screen, etc.) gets smaller than `500px` the order changes (and maybe also one of the margins).

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="flex-item-0"></div>
  <div class="flex-item-0"></div>
  <div class="flex-item-0"></div>
  <div class="flex-item-2"></div>
  <div class="flex-item-2"></div>
  <div class="flex-item-3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-box{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-item-0{
  order: 0;
}
.flex-item-2{
  order: 2;
}
.flex-item-3{
  order: 3;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

and when the `flex-box` gets less than 500px (or whatever specified amount) I want `flex-item-3` to change to:

```
.flex-item-3{
  order: 1;
  /*margin-left: auto;*/
}
```

(I comment out the `margin-left: auto;` so the it is noted that is has been taken out)

I know there are `@media queries` however I am not sure how they would apply in this situation.

Does anyone know how to change a CSS style whenever the containing box gets less than a specific width? (CSS solution preferred but fine with JS/jQuery)

Comment: How is the parent element sized realtive to the window width?

Comment: @Shaggy it's a div element with `display: flex;` so it takes up all of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With CSS, as you said, you can use media queries.

In this case you would use:

```
@media (max-width:500px) {
  .flex-item-3 {
    order: 1;
    margin-left: initial;
  }
}
```

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*---Demo---*/
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #262626;
  /*---Demo---*/
}
.flex-item-0 {
  order: 0;
}
.flex-item-2 {
  order: 2;
}
.flex-item-3 {
  order: 3;
  margin-left: auto;
  /*---Demo---*/
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: tomato;
  /*---Demo---*/
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .flex-item-3 {
    order: 1;
    margin-left: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box">
  <div class="flex-item-0">0</div>
  <div class="flex-item-0">0</div>
  <div class="flex-item-0">0</div>
  <div class="flex-item-2">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-2">2</div>
  <div class="flex-item-3">3</div>
</div>
```